# How to do calculation on eval variables in shell script

Tags: shell-script

I want to do mathematical operations on eval variables in shell script, but it is not working.

```
query=first
eval avgOverall$query[1]=28.5

avgOverall=$(("`eval echo '${avgOverall'$query'[1]}'`+1")) | bc
```

But I am getting below error

```
bash: "28.5+1": syntax error: operand expected (error token is ""28.5+1"")
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Test each part, then you will find the problem.

Answer (score 4):

This is painful to write:

```
avgOverall=$(eval echo '${avgOverall'$query'[1]}' + 1 | bc )
```

If you have bash version 4, use an associative array

```
declare -A avgOverall
avgOverall[$query,1]=28.5
avg=$( bc <<< "${avgOverall[$query,1]} + 1" )
echo $avg
```

Comment: (standard_in) 1: syntax error

Comment: Hi, thanks for the help but i am getting error "(standard_in) 1: syntax error" I am using bash version 4 GNU bash, version 4.2.25(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)

Comment: Sorry my mistake. I have put the wrong variable name. Thanks a lot